# Windows 8.1 - mklink to a folder with files in it

Tags: windows-8.1, symbolic-link, directory-junction

I have a directory 'dir1' with some files in it and a directory 'dir2' where I'll add some files. How can I create a link/junction (or just connect them)? I tried "mklink /D (or /J) dir1 dir2" but apparently it's not working and if it would I think that dir1 would just be dir2. I want dir1 to have the files it has now and when I add files to dir2 to show up in dir1.

Answer (score 1):

#### I tried `mklink /D (or /J) dir1 dir2`

> I have a directory 'dir1' with some files in it and a directory 'dir2' where I'll add some files.

You have the directories the wrong way around. You also need to remove dir2 before creating the link.

The syntax for `mklink` is:

```
MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target
```

Note:

- `mklink` creates the link so `dir2` should not exist before you run the command.

In your case `dir2` will be the new link and `dir1` will be the target, so you need to use:

```
rd dir2
```

Followed by:

```
mklink /d dir2 dir1
```

Or:

```
mklink /j dir2 dir1
```

---

#### Now `dir2` has the files of `dir1` (In other words `dir2` is `dir1`). I don't want that.

That's what **directory links** are designed to do.

You need to rethink.

One option is to add the files to `dir2` and then when in `dir1` create **symbolic link** to the **files** in `dir2`. You can do this with:

```
cd dir1
mklink file \full\path\to\dir2\file
```

You have to do this for every new file added to `dir2`.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [mklink](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) - Create a symbolic link to a directory or a file, or create a hard file link or directory junction.
- [rd](http://ss64.com/nt/rd.html) - Delete folder(s).

Comment: Yeah but now dir2 has the files of dir1 (In other words dir2 is dir1). I don't want that

Comment: @JohnGRThess That's what directory links are designed to do. You need to rethink. One option is to add the files to `dir2` and then when in `dir1` create links to the **files** in `dir2`. You can do this with `mklink file \full\path\to\dir2\file`. You have to do this for every new file added to `dir2`. Answer updated.